# MySQL Sum multiple column values with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following schema (two tables):

```
**APPS**

   | ID (bigint)  | USERID (Bigint) | USAGE_START_TIME (datetime)    | 
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
   |  1           |        12       |         2013-05-03 04:42:55    |
   |  2           |        12       |         2013-05-12 06:22:45    |
   |  3           |        12       |         2013-06-12 08:44:24    |
   |  4           |        12       |         2013-06-24 04:20:56    |
   |  5           |        13       |         2013-06-26 08:20:26    |
   |  6           |        13       |         2013-09-12 05:48:27    |


**USAGE** 

   | ID (bigint)  | APPID (bigint) |   DEVICEID (bigint)  | HIGH_COUNT (bigint) |  MEDIUM_COUNT (bigint)  |
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |  1           |        1       |                  2    |       400           |                   200   |
   |  2           |        1       |                  3    |       200           |                   100   |
   |  3           |        2       |                  3    |       350           |                    40   |
   |  4           |        3       |                  4    |         2           |                   400   |
   |  5           |        4       |                  2    |         4           |                    30   |
   |  6           |        5       |                  3    |        50           |                   300   |
```

Explanation:

So, there are two tables.
Now I want to  find the following:

> Given a USERID, Get sum of HIGH_COUNT & MEDIUM_COUNT. While counting
>   the SUM it should be taken care that: If in USAGE, same device is used
>   more than once, then the record which has the latest info (based on
>   APPS.USAGE_START_TIME), should be considered while calculating the
>   sum.

For ex:

For above schema, result should be (for userid=12) :

```
   | HIGH_COUNT (bigint)  | MEDIUM_COUNT (Bigint) |
    -----------------------------------------------
   |                356   |                   470 |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74ae0f

Comment: There is some confusion in the requirement you mean to say that we should only consider the record which has  highest value using_start_time

Comment: For example....for which userid is the expected result posted??

Comment: I think there is some ambiguity in the question? I am still confused that how you want to latest info and also want to get the sum for a particular user ??

Comment: So you want to only add unique record on date basis??

Comment: Hi all, if there are more than one usage records with same device_id, i want to take into consideration the records with max (latest) usage_start_time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user uses multiple `APPS` on one device, this query will use the `APPS` row with the highest `usage_start_time`:

```
select  a.userid
,       sum(u.high_count)
,       sum(u.medium_count)
from    apps a
join    `usage` u
on      u.appid = a.id
join    (
        select  u.device_id
        ,       a.userid
        ,       max(a.usage_start_time) as max_start_time
        from    apps a
        join    `usage` u
        on      u.appid = a.id
        group by
                u.device_id
        ,       a.userid
        ) filter
on      filter.device_id = u.device_id
        and filter.userid = a.userid
        and filter.max_start_time = a.usage_start_time
group by
        a.userid
```

In your dataset, it will select usage rows `5, 3, 4` for user `12`.

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29aad/9/0)

Comment: @sash: This answer is per user.  Your example answer is with users 12 and 13 combined.  Does that explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite get your numbers, but something like this should work...

```
SELECT a.userid
     , SUM(u.high_count)
     , SUM(u.medium_count)
  FROM apps a
  JOIN `usage` u
    ON u.appid = a.id
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT userid
            , deviceid
            , MAX(usage_start_time) max_usage_start_time
         FROM apps a
         JOIN `usage` u
           ON u.appid = a.id
        GROUP
           BY userid
            , deviceid
     ) x
    ON x.userid = a.userid
   AND x.deviceid = u.deviceid
   AND x.max_usage_start_time = a.usage_start_time
 GROUP
    BY userid;
```

Note that `usage` is a reserved word. Therefore, this is a bad name for a column (or a table). Also, note inconsistencies between your question and your fiddle.

Comment: That's because you've made a mistake :-)

Answer (score -2):

I think not had chance to test it but

```
SELECT SUM(HIGH_COUNT), SUM(MEDIUM_COUNT) FROM `USAGE` INNER JOIN `APPS` ON USAGE.APPID=APPS.ID WHERE APPS.USERID=$input_user_id_to_lookup
```

will give you your counts.

For yoru other question (homework?) you didn't give us the full schema so we can't guess what you need doing.

Also whoever designed that db should be shot its horrible

Comment: I read it perfectly fine and the query answers his question 100% with the information he had currently posted.  We cannot allow for his start time field has he hadn't (at time of me posting) provided the data types of the start time column so we had/have no method of selecting latest entry based off start date.